# PHP logout failed, unset($_SESSION['user']) does not work

Tags: php, html, session

This has been a problem for more than week, and I started to believe it has something with other than the code!

This is my session page:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('dbConfigBDO.php');
include('SafeRedirect.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    safe_redirect('login.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

I set `$_SESSION['login_user']` after login and call `session.php` in every page.  I also have a logout page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'SafeRedirect.php';
unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
session_destroy();
safe_redirect('login.php');
?>
```

The problem here even after logout I still can access my pages which I was trying to prevent by using sessions.

What could be possibly wrong?

Edit: my `SafeRedirect.php` page, I used it from [here](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/secure-redirect.htm)

```
<?php
function safe_redirect($url, $exit=true) {
    if (!headers_sent()){

        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: ' . $url);

        header("Connection: close");
    }

    print '<html>';
    print '<head><title>Redirecting you...</title>';
    print '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
    print '</head>';
    print '<body onload="location.replace(\''.$url.'\')">';

    print 'You should be redirected to this URL:<br />';
    print "<a href=$url>'$url'</a><br /><br />";

    print 'If you are not, please click on the link above.<br />';

    print '</body>';
    print '</html>';

    if ($exit) exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you post SafeRedirect.php contents?

Comment: I did, and Thanks for the edit!

Comment: I am going to be very honest, I am not seeing the issue..

Comment: The same for me, the real problem is it used to work in another project :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you require `session.php` after

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
          safe_redirect('login.php');
          die();
       }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the $_SESSION['login_user']?

Comment: Could be you initialize the variable before asking if it's isset and calling safe_redirect() ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not necessary from the php. It maybe some problem from the browser caching some data. Have you tried these heads in your html ?

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: nothing changed, I added this to my index and login pages.

Comment: The index.php still see the user logged in ?